# sudo freshclam problems

Tags: clamav

When I put following in terminal:

```bsh
 sudo mkdir /var/log/clamav
 sudo chown -R clamav:adm /var/log/clamav/
 sudo chown -R clamav:clamav /var/log/clamav/
 sudo freshclam
```

I can succesfully get virus update after running these commands.
However, after some time I get an error.

I think after I use STACER  application to clean system ( actually not necessary to clean )

```
joso@joso-aspirees1433:~$ sudo freshclam
[sudo] password for joso: 
ERROR: Can't open /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log in append mode (check permissions!).
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
ERROR: initialize: libfreshclam init failed.
ERROR: Initialization error!
joso@joso-aspirees1433:~$
```

but after I run commands in terminal it gives updated freshclam:

```
joso@joso-aspirees1433:~$ sudo su 
[sudo] password for joso: 
root@joso-aspirees1433:/home/joso# sudo mkdir /var/log/clamav
root@joso-aspirees1433:/home/joso# sudo chown -R clamav:adm /var/log/clamav/
root@joso-aspirees1433:/home/joso# sudo chown -R clamav:clamav /var/log/clamav/
root@joso-aspirees1433:/home/joso# sudo freshclam
Tue Oct 26 06:53:26 2021 -> ClamAV update process started at Tue Oct 26 06:53:26 2021
Tue Oct 26 06:53:26 2021 -> daily.cld database is up-to-date (version: 26333, sigs: 1939856, f-level: 90, builder: raynman)
Tue Oct 26 06:53:26 2021 -> main.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, f-level: 90, builder: sigmgr)
Tue Oct 26 06:53:26 2021 -> bytecode.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 333, sigs: 92, f-level: 63, builder: awillia2)
root@joso-aspirees1433:/home/joso#
```

How do I keep these settings permanent  ?

Comment: Your question does not actually describe the problem you are experiencing, nor does it tell us what end goal you are trying to accomplish. Edit your question and include the error as well as any other essential diagnostic information to help identify the problem.  You should also include the output of the commands that you are running. Please copy/paste and use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) for terminal output.

Comment: You write "after some time I get an error" - so, as Nmath stated, tell us the error you got so we can help!  ;>

Comment: I updated my question giving more information